# PHP - How to copy a file to other location?

Tags: php, copy

I need to develop a PHP script that will be able to select files from the server to copy them to the same server but to another directory.

I need to select the file like if I was selecting a file from my local computer.

This is possible? What steps should I take to begin with this script? There are any tutorials out there that exemplifies this scenario?

Best Regards,

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Search google for "php file upload"...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not a normal file upload. I have to list the files in the server, instead of list the files in my local drive

Comment: `I need to select the file like if I was selecting a file from my local computer.` Do you need to build a web-based file manager or something?

Answer (score 2):

Use [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) or [copy()](http://hu2.php.net/copy).

Answer (score 2):

```
copy($sourceFile, $destinationFile);
```

If $destinationFile exists, it will be overwritten.

UPDATE:

To read the filelist in a specific directory you can use this function:

```
function dirlist($directory){

    if (is_dir($directory)){

        if ($handle = opendir($directory)){

            while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
                $files[] = $file;
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    return $files;

}
```